# Foco em uma aba do navegador com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end

Com JavaScript é possível dar foco em uma aba específica do navegador, supondo que eu saiba qual essa aba? Se sim, como?

Answer (score 1):

Lucas,

como mencionado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123950/javascript-how-to-make-a-browser-switch-tabs) não existe um método efetivo e 100% confiável para se acionar uma aba especifica do browser.

Você pode utilizar a função [window.focus()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_focus.asp), mas se lembre que ela provavelmente estará bloqueada na maioria dos browsers, então não deixe que a sua aplicação dependa dessa função.

Exemplo:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100");   // Abre uma nova janela
myWindow.document.write("<p>A new window!</p>");         // Adiciona um texto na nova janela
myWindow.focus();                                     // Passa o foco para nova janela.
```